# mod_rewrite on .htaccess file split locally from remote

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Essentially I'm looking to improve the following code...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(control|admin|scripts|É)(/|$) - [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$0 -d
RewriteRule ^[^/]+ - [L]


# Local

RewriteRule ^([a-z-]*)/$ index.php?a=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]*)/([a-z-]*)/$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]*)/([a-z-]*)/([a-z-]*)/$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L]


# Local/live (Rackspace Cloud Sites)

# RewriteRule ^([a-z-]*)/$ /index.php?a=$1 [L] 
# RewriteRule ^([a-z-]*)/([a-z-]*)/$ /index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
# RewriteRule ^([a-z-]*)/([a-z-]*)/([a-z-]*)/$ /index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L]
```

You will notice there is a set of redirects for my local machine and a set for when uploaded on the server (Rackspace Cloud Sites). For some reason the re-directs locally can't have a / before the index. Ideally I would like to to combine the 2, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Absolutely perfect - your a legend! Cheers dude.

Comment: Spoke to soon, doesn't work :(

Comment: Spoke to soon, doesn't work :(